# Angular 2 - Select clicked list item (Add 'active' class and remove from siblings)

Tags: angular

I have list items as follows in below code snippet. On mouse click I would like to select that item (add 'active' class and deselect if any other items (siblings) selected by remove'active class. I have achieved the same using jQuery (full code below). How I can achieve the functionality in Angular 2 way.

Code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="grouplist" class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Item1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item4</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item5</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item6</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item7</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item8</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item9</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item10</li>
</ul>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.list-group li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rkrishna/x1nmhwtv/)

Angular 2 Experiment: I am able to set class via 'setElementClass'. How to remove 'active' class from siblings? Or is there any other approaches?

List view component (test1.component.html):

```
<h2>Select List Item</h2>

<ul id="grouplist" class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" (click)="listClick($event)" *ngFor="let item of groups">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

TypeScript Code (test1.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Group } from './group';

@Component({
    selector: 'test1',
    template: require('./test1.component.html')
})
export class Test1Component {

    groups: Group[];

    constructor(private render: Renderer) {
        this.groups = [new Group("item1"), new Group("item2"), new Group("item3"), new Group("item4"), new Group("item5")];
    }

    public listClick(event: any) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.render.setElementClass(event.target, "active", true);
        // How to remove 'active' from siblings ?
    }
}
```

group.ts

```
export class Group {
    constructor(public name: String) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Angular 2 or Angular 1 ? It would be good to see what you've done so far, so we can improve/correct it. This seems to be just asking us for the complete answer.

Comment: Angular 2 - Updated my question with my Angular 2 code.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use ngClass for what you are looking for:

```
 <ul id="grouplist" class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == item}" (click)="listClick($event, item)" *ngFor="let item of groups">
        {{ item.name }}
     </li>
</ul>
```

And in your `listClick` just set the selected item to that item:

```
listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;  // don't forget to update the model here
    // ... do other stuff here ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Yaser. In the given code (listClick()), please let me know how to set the selected item. Sorry if it is a basic question, I am quite new to Angular 2.

Comment: if i update the model object inside the click handler, how will i able to refresh the template html.

Comment: @Karan if by updating the model you mean `item` then either you need to fire an event or trigger the change detection manually

Comment: @Yaser I've got a similar case. what if it should be used for chat list and each chat list item has (click)="GoToChatPage(chat.receiverId.username)" and opens messages on the right for that selected chat list user with you?
I've posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691060/how-to-add-active-class-on-selected-chat-list-item-angular
How can I refactor this code to fit for my issue?

Comment: @Artur answered your question

Comment: what happen if user reload the page? I think the selection will go. Can you have solution for that?

Comment: In that case you need to store the selection in the local storage and retrieve it on load, then assign it to your local variable to get the job done. Have a look at this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536262/angular-6-saving-data-to-local-storage

Comment: How to active first li starting?

Answer (score 21):

You can also just pass the index of the `li` element to your component during a click event:

```
<ul id="grouplist" class="list-group">
   <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" (click)="select(i)" 
       [ngClass]="{'active': selectedIndex == i, 'list-group-item': true}" >
      {{ item.text }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then let you component set its `selectedIndex`property:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ItemListComponent {
  ...
  selectedIndex: number;
  select(index: number) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
  }
}
```

The `selectedIndex`is used by the template to determine whether to assign the `active` class to the `li` element.

See it in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tw1cBG13EoNSM3nkzekS?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for the answer. This one also works as expected. Since Yaser give the answer first, accepted that answer. Sorry, I'm able to select only one answer.

Comment: @Frank. Sir can you please answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154020/how-to-apply-css-dynamically-on-selected-items-only-angular?noredirect=1#comment104533181_59154020

Comment: @Frank Fajardo this is the simpliest solution I ever had

Answer (score 0):

For those who aren't convinced with the accepted solution and coming from an AngularJS background, here's a solution for you.

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let quality of qualities" 
    [ngClass]="quality.id === activeElement ? 'active' : 'none'"
    (click)="selectedItem(quality.id)"
    >
  {{quality.quality}}
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color : #ffffff;
}
```

Component:

```
public activeElement = 1;  
public selectedItem(id) {
    this.activeElement = id;
 }
```

Note : My ngFor's collection is like 
    qlist = [
      {
        quality: 'About Me',
        id: 1
      }]
So, I'm using quality.id to switch the class, you can use your own attribute to switch. Just change the activeElement variable to whatever you want to make it default.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<ul id="grouplist" class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == item}" 
     (click)="listClick($event, item)" *ngFor="let item of groups">
        {{ item.name }}
     </li>
    </ul>
```

```html
listClick(event, newValue) {
     console.log(newValue);
     this.selectedItem = newValue;  // don't forget to update the model here
     // ... do other stuff here ...
    }
```

To apply active class on click of selected item & remove it from another element click

```
onClickOfOtherElement(){
  this.selectedItem = ''
}
```