# Storage of data downloaded from the API

Tags: angular

I need a clue. How can I store data downloaded from the API?

- All data downloading functions can be found in Service
- I have several components
- In one component I have a button that calls for downloading data from the API (Service injected through the constructor)

Where should this data be saved so that other components can use it?

If I return a value in the component in which the button was pressed from the data retrieval function, then only in this component I will have this data.

Comment: The best use would be a database where you push all your data to. For example a specific table that stores the data of a specific endpoint. That way you can read the data in the other components.

Comment: Maybe [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to save it in LocalStorage, but it depends based on your needs.

Check this one if it helps: [Angular 6: saving data to local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536262/angular-6-saving-data-to-local-storage)

LocalStorage is very well supported on different browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: It is important that in the case of data changes, the components using these data are also refreshed.

Comment: You can achieve this with a service watching for changes. It will update the local storage and emits corespondent changes to subscribed components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Storage (Session storage and Local storage), but it depends on size of data. Local Storage and Session storage can store up to 10 MB i think, bit if your data size is much bigger , reconsider using **IndexedDB**. Here is a link to read:
https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb