# defer() does not fire effect on page refresh

Tags: angular, rxjs, deferred, ngrx-store

I am trying to implement simple user authentication, and currently I am working on preventing user logout on page refresh. For that I am using defer  . First time when app is opened defer return AuthActions.Logout() which is correct because there is no authentication the problem is with refresh because although token is set in a chrome storage and all actions are dispatched **effect is not called again**.

```
@Effect()
init$ = defer((): Observable<AuthActions.SigninUser | AuthActions.Logout> => {
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    console.log('in def')
    return (token)
        ? of(new AuthActions.SigninUser())
        : of(new AuthActions.Logout())
});
```

then it goes here ->

```
@Effect()
            login$ = this.actions$
                .pipe(
                    ofType(AuthActions.SIGNIN_USER),
                    switchMap(() => {
                        console.log('signin user')
                        return [new UserDetailsActions.GetUserDetails];
                    }),
                )
```

if token is set (which is) this should be fired but it is fired only once when user sign in ->

```
 @Effect()
    getUserById = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(UserDetailsActions.GET_USER_DETAILS),
            mergeMap(() => {
                let token = this.authService.getTokenUsername();
                return this.http.get(`${AppProperties.API_URL}user/${token}`)
            }),
            concatMap((userDetails: UserDetails) => {
                sessionStorage.setItem('currentUserId', userDetails.id.toString());
                return [new UserDetailsActions.SetUserDetails(userDetails)]
            })
        );
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use Local storage to keep user login.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: When user log in, store token into browser's LocalStorage. For more information have look at [Angular 6: saving data to local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536262/angular-6-saving-data-to-local-storage)

Comment: unfortunately will not change anything. new UserDetailsActions.GetUserDetails is dispatched on page refresh butgetUserById effect is not fired again