# Using local storage on Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, local-storage, phonebook

I'm trying to make a simple phonebook using Angular, but I'm struggling with making my "app" store the information inserted to local storage.

Here is what I have so far, so if anyone has time to take a peak, I would appreciate it very much.

https://easyupload.io/m/uk7r3f

Comment: Provide code example please :)

Comment: My apologies. I have uploaded screenshots since as new user stack overflow won't allow me to upload.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/m/uk7r3f

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object and adds a data item to it using [`Storage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

The syntax for reading the `localStorage` item is as follows:

```
const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

The syntax for removing the `localStorage` item is as follows:

```
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
```

The syntax for removing all the `localStorage` items is as follows:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

**Note:** Please refer to the [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) article for a full example.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example

Answer (score 0):

you can use setItem, getItem, removeItem methods to perform CRUD operation using localStorage

```
   localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

For more information you can follow:
[Add DATA in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536262/angular-6-saving-data-to-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

**localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')** = > allows you to store an item in the browser storage

**localStorage.getItem('key')**  = > allows you to read the value for the specified key item from the browser storage.
for more information : https://www.journaldunet.fr/web-tech/developpement/1441263-comment-gerer-le-stockage-en-local-dans-la-session-d-un-navigateur-avec-angular/