# Angular HTTP request returns undefined the first time

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, http, observable

I have a service with such a HTTP request:
`

```
    login(email:any,password:any){
          this.http.post<{token:string}>('http://localhost:3000/login',{payload:{email,password}},{
          headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
        }).pipe().subscribe(res=>{this.token=res.token})
    }
```

`a variavle` 
`private token!: string;`
`and a helper function:`

```
    getToken() {
        console.log(this.token)
        return this.token;
      }
```

`

The problem is that when the first time I call getToken() I get an Undefined and only if I call it one more time I get a valid value.

Comment: Please try to convert your login function to the async function.  Use the `async/await ` mechanism.  Please make sure that the login function and API call has to be completed before making a call to `getToken` function. There is a chance of delay since it's an API call.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the login function and API call has to be completed before making a call to `getToken` function. There is a chance of delay since it's an API call.

Saving tokens in a local variable isn't a good practice since you need to call the API when refreshing the browser. Try to save tokens in [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536284/6720372) rather than saving in a local variable.

```
login(email:any,password:any){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.http.post<{token:string}>('http://localhost:3000/login',{payload:{email,password}},{
            headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
        }).pipe().subscribe(res=>{this.token=res.token})
    },3000)
}
```

OR

```
 login(email:any,password:any){
    this.http.post<{token:string}>('http://localhost:3000/login',{payload:{email,password}},{
        headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    }).pipe().subscribe(res=>{ localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
    })
}

getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token')
}
```