# How to check if user is still logged in in ASP.NET Core Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies, websecurity

I created an ASP.NET Core Web Api project with Visual Studio. It uses .NET 6.0, controllers and Swagger. The default structure is the below:

[image]

Right now I have two controllers more:

- *UsersController*

  ```
  [ApiController]
  [Authorize] // <------- all endpoints are protected with cookie auth
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class UsersController : ControllerBase { ... }
  ```

That class contains the below endpoint with a simple get operation:

**/GET /api/users**

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var users = await _userService.GetAll();
    return Ok(users);
}
```

- *AuthenticationController*

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody] Credentials credentials) { ... }
  ```

**/POST /api/authenticate**

```
[AllowAnonymous] // <------ so we can call it with no cookie present in the request
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody] Credentials credentials)
{
    var isAuthenticated = _cookieService.Authenticate(credentials.Username, credentials.Password);

    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        var userId = _cookieService.CreateCookie(userData.Username, Request.HttpContext);
        var completeUserData = await _userService.GetById(userId);
        var partialUserData = _mapper.Map<PartialUserDataDto>(completeUserData );
    return Ok(partialUserData);
    }
    
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

`_cookeService.Authenticate(...)` just checks against an in memory dictionary if username and password exists (ex. { username: test1, password: pass1 }).
`partialUserData` is an object containing some user fields to show them in the frontend (ex. username, role, email, etc.).

In `Program.cs` I use authentication and authorization middleware with cookies like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie(x =>
{
    x.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;  // only for dev mode
    x.SlidingExpiration = true;
    x.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = redirectContext =>
        {
            redirectContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

...

app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
    }
);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

1. The browser makes a `/POST /authentication { username: test1, password: pass1 }`
2. The server checks whether the user exists in a dictionary in memory
3. If it exists, it returns a cookie along some user data
4. In my Angular frontend, I save that user data in a `currentUser` object that contains, among other data, the user role
5. An auth guard renders the view based on the user role.
6. I can naviagate to other views and make requests to the API because the browser sends automatically the cookie in step 3 to the server

### My problem

7. If I refresh the browser, I lose my `currentUser` object. I don't want to consider this a logout since I still have the cookie in the browser. But the user data was stored in memory, so obviously I lost it. Should I create a new **protected** endpoint like `GET /user/<id>` to get again the user data? Is it a good practice?

My goal is that, as long as I have the cookie in the browser, I consider the user is logged in so they don't need to enter their credentials in the login box each time they enter to the app or navigate to a different view. Also, as long I have the same cookie, the user can make any API request to the server. This is, I use the cookie for authentication and also for authorization.

I'm quite confused and don't know if this is a good approach.

Comment: have you tried HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated?

Comment: How would that help me?

Comment: How about using [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services)? [Controller](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Web/V3/AccountController.cs#L537-L544) - [Repository](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L340-L344) - [AddIdentity](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Extensions/MintPlayerExtensions.cs#L31)

Comment: @Pieterjan From the documentation I understand Identity is for Razor Pages, Blazor or MVC web apps, not pure web API's. So I don't know how to use Identity with my web API.

Comment: For mobile apps use Bearer authentication [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Api/V1/AccountController.cs#L69-L75)

Comment: For single page applications, [use cookie authentication + XSRF protection](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe) - [Here's a dotnet template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates)

Comment: Yes, I tried both cookies and JWT's but I'm still confused about if using cookies for both authentication and authorization along session management is a good practice. Assuming the client is a browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if user is still logged in, You can create an endpoint to check it. Here I create a endpoint to check the user:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CheckController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public bool islogin()
        {
            var result = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Then in the conmponent's constructor method in angular, I will send HttpClient to this endpoint to check if user is still logged in.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private http: HttpClient){
      //......
      this.http.get('https://localhost:7239/api/Check',{ withCredentials: true }).subscribe((x)=>{
          if(x===true){
            this.IsloggedIn = "User has logged in"
          }else{
            this.IsloggedIn = "User has logged out"
          }
      })
      
    }

    IsloggedIn : string = "";
```

In the form submit method, I will also change the value of `IsloggedIn`

```
onSubmit() {
 this.http.post('https://localhost:7239/Login',this.contactForm.value,{withCredentials: true}).subscribe((x:any) =>{
    this.user.UserName = x.userName,
    this.user.PassWord = x.passWord,
    this.user.Age = x.age
    this.IsloggedIn = "User has logged in"
  })
}
```

Gif demo

[image]

Now if user refresh the browser, The data saved in currentUser object will be removed, Because of the httpclient in constructor, It will send request to the endpoint to check if user is still logged in. Then it show the information to remind user he is still logged in or not.

[image]

If you want to show the data saved in currentUser object after refresh, another method is to save this data in local storage after you get value from backend, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536262/angular-6-saving-data-to-local-storage).

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in your answer. One question though: what type of application are you running? Razor Pages, Blazor, MVC, Web API, etc.?

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC Asp.net core web api

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC Web Api use JWT token authentication in most case, but you can also use cookie authentication, refer to this [docs](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/).

Comment: Who fills the value of `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`? Is it the authentication middleware when it receives the cookie from the browser?

Comment: yes, When a user logs in and the server validates their credentials, the authentication middleware generates an authentication token (such as a cookie) and sends it to the client. On subsequent requests, the client includes this token in the request headers, and the authentication middleware verifies the token and sets the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property to true if the token is valid.

Comment: Could you add the code where you configure the cookies middleware? Do you use any cookie service? In the backend side, I mean. Right now, I have a cookie implementation which returns OK or Unauthorized based on certain validation. But I don't use at all `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is in an individual endpoint, In my login endpoint, I also return OK or unauthorize. In your question. if the cookie has expired, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will return false, It is a very simple way to check if user is still logged in. You can also write  your method to check if user is still logged in.