# How to add active class on selected chat list item (Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We are trying to complete this chat component. When the user clicks on the left side chat item it opens messages with that chosen user. We have an active class that changes chat list item color. Trying to implement active class when the user selects any chat list item. Here is the code:

**Messages service**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from '@angular/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_ast';

const BASEURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/chatapp';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  SendMessage(senderId, receiverId, receiverName, message): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${BASEURL}/chat-messages/${senderId}/${receiverId}`, {
      receiverId,
      receiverName,
      message
    });
  }

  GetAllMessages(senderId, receiverId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${BASEURL}/chat-messages/${senderId}/${receiverId}`);
  }

  MarkMessages(sender, receiver): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${BASEURL}/receiver-messages/${sender}/${receiver}`);
  }

  MarkAllMessages(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${BASEURL}/mark-all-messages`);
  }

  chatSelected = new EventEmitter<Message>();
}
```

**Route**

```
path: 'chat/:name',
component: MessageComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="frame">
        <div id="sidepanel">
            <div id="contacts" >
                <ul *ngFor="let chat of chatList">
                    <li class="contact" 
[ngClass]="{'active': chat.receiverId.username === this.selectedChat.receiverId.username}">
                        <div class="wrap" (click)="GoToChatPage(chat.receiverId.username)">
                            <span class="contact-status online"></span>
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/ratingapp/image/upload/v{{chat.receiverId.picVersion}}/{{chat.receiverId.picId}}" alt="" />
                            <div class="meta">
                                <p class="name">{{chat.receiverId.username}}</p>
                                <p class="preview">
                                        {{chat.msgId.message[chat.msgId.message.length - 1].body.substr(0, 10)}}...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="contact-profile">
                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" />
                <p>Harvey Specter</p>
                <div class="social-media">
                    <i class="material-icons">cancel</i>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="messages">
                <ul *ngFor="let message of messagesArray">

                    <li class="sent" *ngIf="user.username !== receiver && user.username !== message.sendername">
                        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/ratingapp/image/upload/v{{chat.receiverId.picVersion}}/{{chat.receiverId.picId}}" alt="" />
                        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="replies" *ngIf="user.username === message.sendername">
                        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/ratingapp/image/upload/v{{chat.receiverId.picVersion}}/{{chat.senderId.picId}}" alt="" />
                        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form (ngSubmit)="SendMessage()">
            <div class="message-input">
                <div class="wrap">
                <input [(ngModel)]="message" (keypress)="IsTyping()" type="text" placeholder="Write your message..." />
                <button class="emojiBtn" (click)="Toggled()"></button>
                <div class="emoji-content-editable" (emojiPickerCaretEmitter)="HandleCurrentCaret($event)" (input)="content = $event.target.textContent"
                [textContent]="content" contenteditable="true"></div>

              <i class="emoji-toggle-button imgBtn" [(emojiPickerIf)]="toggled" [emojiPickerPreserveSelection]="false" [emojiPickerDirection]="direction"
                [emojiPickerAutofocus]="true" (emojiPickerSelect)="HandleSelection($event)"></i>
                <button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() users;
  receiver: string;
  user: any;
  message: string;
  receiverData: any;
  messagesArray = [];
  socket: any;
  typingMessage;
  typing = false;
  isOnline = false;
  chatList = [];

  public eventMock;
  public eventPosMock;

  public direction =
    Math.random() > 0.5 ? (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'top' : 'bottom') : Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'right' : 'left';
  public toggled = false;
  public content = ' ';

  private _lastCaretEvent: CaretEvent;

  constructor(
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private msgService: MessageService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private usersService: UsersService
  ) {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.tokenService.GetPayload();
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.receiver = params.name;
      this.GetUserByUsername(this.receiver);

      this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
        this.GetUserByUsername(this.receiver);
      });
    });

    this.socket.on('is_typing', data => {
      if (data.sender === this.receiver) {
        this.typing = true;
      }
    });

    this.socket.on('has_stopped_typing', data => {
      if (data.sender === this.receiver) {
        this.typing = false;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const title = document.querySelector('.nameCol');
    if (changes.users.currentValue.length > 0) {
      const result = _.indexOf(changes.users.currentValue, this.receiver);
      if (result > -1) {
        this.isOnline = true;
        (title as HTMLElement).style.marginTop = '10px';
      } else {
        this.isOnline = false;
        (title as HTMLElement).style.marginTop = '20px';
      }
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const params = {
      room1: this.user.username,
      room2: this.receiver
    };

    this.socket.emit('join chat', params);
  }

  GetUser(id) {
    this.usersService.GetUserById(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.chatList = data.result.chatList;
    });
  }

  GetUserByUsername(name) {
    this.usersService.GetUserByName(name).subscribe(data => {
      this.receiverData = data.result;

      this.GetMessages(this.user._id, data.result._id);
    });
  }

  GoToChatPage(chat, name) {
        this.selectedChat = chat;
        this.router.navigate(['chat', name]);
        this.msgService.MarkMessages(this.user.username, name).subscribe(data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
        });
      }

  GetMessages(senderId, receiverId) {
    this.msgService.GetAllMessages(senderId, receiverId).subscribe(data => {
      this.messagesArray = data.messages.message;
    });
  }

  SendMessage() {
    if (this.message) {
      this.msgService
        .SendMessage(this.user._id, this.receiverData._id, this.receiverData.username, this.message)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          this.message = '';
        });
    }
  }

  HandleSelection(event: EmojiEvent) {
    this.content =
      this.content.slice(0, this._lastCaretEvent.caretOffset) +
      event.char +
      this.content.slice(this._lastCaretEvent.caretOffset);
    this.eventMock = JSON.stringify(event);
    this.message = this.content;

    this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    this.content = '';
  }

  HandleCurrentCaret(event: CaretEvent) {
    this._lastCaretEvent = event;
    this.eventPosMock = `{ caretOffset : ${event.caretOffset}, caretRange: Range{...}, textContent: ${
      event.textContent
    } }`;
  }

  Toggled() {
    this.toggled = !this.toggled;
  }

  IsTyping() {
    this.socket.emit('start_typing', {
      sender: this.user.username,
      receiver: this.receiver
    });

    if (this.typingMessage) {
      clearTimeout(this.typingMessage);
    }

    this.typingMessage = setTimeout(() => {
      this.socket.emit('stop_typing', {
        sender: this.user.username,
        receiver: this.receiver
      });
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

I thought adding event emitter but have no idea how will it work in this case. So how can I add active class on left chat list item when user selects a chat user from left chat list and it opens messages with that user on the right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of all the logic in there, but the solution is very simple:

1- Keep a variable containing the current `user` (from route), which you already have => `this.receiver`.

2- Use `[class]` to add `active` to each element.

```
<li class="content" [ngClass]="{'active': chat.receiverId.username === this.receiver}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't get one point. Should we add ng class to ul? I am asking it because li gets the active class.

Comment: I've included your code inside my code in the question, Should the final look like that?

Comment: Wait why are you navigating away? If you navigate and come back the object is gone, you have to use router to detect which chat is selected

Comment: I am confused. last week I posted another question for that since didn't get any answer used navigation instead. So what should I remove from above?

Comment: If you give me more context, I might be able to better help, if by clicking one of the chat items you just need to load it's conversation, you don't need navigation, just an http call and assigning it to the variable.

Comment: You are right that's what I am trying to achieve. " if by clicking one of the chat items you just need to load it's conversation," I've found this chat component from a tutorial where chat list doesn't exist at all. from menu drop down you selected the person with who you have a chat and navigated to the separated rout with their messages. I tried to create a mix and achieved to this result.

Comment: I've included all codes here just now related to this component.

Comment: That is perfect, updated the answer to match what you have, you already have the  name of receiver from route @Artur

Comment: Great. What about the previous TS which you added? Should I keep it as in my edited code in the question?

Comment: I am asking it because it shows a red line under this.selected chat in ts.

Comment: No that's not necessary