# Routerlinkactive not working on dynamically generated route on page load in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8, angular-routerlink

I have an app build with Angular 8. `Routerlinkactive` is not activated on dynamically generated route at the beginning, but when I click on some other links in the same module and come back then it works.
The `routerLinkActive` is set in the `UserComponent`, and it should activate the anchor in navigation  when the child (`UserProfileComponent`) is loaded based on **url params**.

[image]

I tried many solutions such as usage of template variable, for example

`[routerLinkActive]="['']" [ngClass]="rla.isActive ? 'mat-accent' : 'mat-primary'" #rla="routerLinkActive"`
or applied `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"` but none of them were helpfull.

This is last version of my HTML code.

```
<ul role="list"  class="list-horizontal">
  <li>
    <a class="mat-primary"
      routerLinkActive="mat-accent"
      [routerLink]="'/user/profile/' + profile?._id"
      mat-raised-button>Profile </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="mat-primary"
      [routerLink]="'/user/posts/'"
      [routerLinkActive]="['mat-accent']"
      mat-raised-button>Posts</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="mat-primary"
      [routerLink]="'/user/favorite-posts/'"
      [routerLinkActive]="['mat-accent']"
      mat-raised-button>Favourites</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I guess the problem is in dynamically generated route ( which is based on user id ),

For example `http://my-domain/user/profile/5dd58c41409cccea2c9296f3` because when I access other components directly, for instance `http://my-domain/user/posts` then `routerLinkActive` works fine sets `active` class to the corresponding link.
This is how my routes are configured for current module.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile/:id',
        component: UserProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'posts',
        component: UserPostsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'favorite-posts',
        component: UserFavoritePostsComponent
      }
    ]
}];
```

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try to define `userLink` as something like this: `[routerLink]="['user', 'profile', profile._id"`

Comment: actually Itried this option, but I guess url params usually are loaded a bit late therefore request goes with 'null' value in the end of url.

Comment: yes, it might be that, so you maybe add *ngIf on the li element to check weather profile is already loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I found another method to solve this problem, since I could not display active route with dynamically generated parameters. Therefore I am posting my answer so it might help others.

I decided to set `mat-accent` (active) class on selected element and remove that class from sibling elements. The trick is done with the help of `ngClass` directive.

Here is my updated HTML. (`routerLinkActive` property is not needed any more)

```
<ul role="list"  class="list-horizontal mb-15">
  <li>
    <a
      class="mat-primary"
      routerLinkActive="mat-accent"
      [routerLink]="'/user/profile/' + profile?._id"
      [ngClass]="{'mat-accent': selectedItem == 'profile'}"
      (click)="onSetActiveClass($event, 'profile')"
      mat-raised-button>Profile </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a
      class="mat-primary"
      [routerLink]="'/user/posts/' + profile?._id"
      [ngClass]="{'mat-accent': selectedItem == 'posts'}"
      (click)="onSetActiveClass($event, 'posts')"
      mat-raised-button>Posts</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a
      class="mat-primary"
      [routerLink]="'/user/favorite-posts/'"
      [ngClass]="{'mat-accent': selectedItem == 'favorite-posts'}"
      (click)="onSetActiveClass($event, 'favorite-posts')"
      mat-raised-button>Favourites</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in typescript file:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.onSetActiveClass(event, 'profile'); // pass the 'active' class on load
}

onSetActiveClass(event, newClass) {
        this.selectedItem = newClass;
}
```

Here is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40988072/3578809).
Good luck! :)